# Cannot run devbind --status, command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, network-programming, dpdk

I'm trying to install DPDK on Ubuntu 22.04.

If I run `dpdk-devbind --status` I get `command not found`

For installation I ran these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk.git
meson setup build
cd build
ninja
ninja install
```

It hasn't installed to `/usr/local/lib64`. The only location I can see is `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk` and a lot of DPDK binaries in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

What am I missing to run `dpdk-devbind --status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the DPDK documentation is falling short (again) and not mentioning that it's a python script, `dpdk-devbind.py`, which comes from the `usertools` subdirectory and for me got installed in `/usr/local/bin/` using default options.

It should have executable permissions, so you can call it like:

- `dpdk-devbind.py --status` to see the current drivers in use for each adapter and also which one(s) is(are) unused, such as vfio-pci or uio_pci_generic
- `sudo dpdk-devbind.py --unbind 00:03.0` to unbind the adapter from any driver
- `sudo modprobe uio_pci_generic && sudo dpdk-devbind.py --bind uio_pci_generic 00:03.0` to load the uio_pci_generic driver (obviously not needed if already done) and bind the specified adapter to that driver
- `dpdk-devbind.py --status` at this point would list 00:03.0 under the list of DPDK-compatible drivers

You may have to use `vfio_pci` instead of `uio_pci_generic` as the driver, depending on your hardware.  On a bare-metal machine with intel cards, I use `vfio-pci`, but in an Ubuntu VM, I had to add a second network adapter (as a bridge-adapter), which I also allowed to enter promiscuous mode in the VirtualBox GUI settings, and for which I had to use `uio_pci_generic`.

Comment: Also, if you're using Ubuntu, these notes are for an older version, but are still very helpful:  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dpdk

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you so much for this answer. Eventually I got the unbind and bind working. I've ran HelloWorld and that works. I tried Skeleton but I get that "even number of ports" error. Presume this means I need a second NIC? And I should connect the two NICs with a short Ethernet cable?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a second NIC; you can always rx/tx on a single one, but you have to change the code around or use an example that doesn't require two.  Skeleton is a good basic program and you should be able to modify it fairly quickly to just use a single port.  It's not as complicated as it seems at first glance.  If you want a program that works out-of-the-box with a single NIC, you can try testpmd or pktgen.  I like pktgen, because it has a nice "graphical ASCII" UI with help, whereas testpmd has great control, but is purely CLI-based and you'll need to read the doc's.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between vfio_pci and uio_pci_generic? I can't get vfio_pci to work, I get `Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio_pci/bind: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio_pci/bind'`

Comment: I did some Googling and `rdmsr 0x3a` returns 5, which apparently means VT-d is enabled.

Comment: If that's the case (that VT-d is disabled), that should be something you can enable in BIOS.  You'll also need to follow the steps to turn on iommu as a kernel parameter, as described in [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html)

Comment: I think it's enabled- I saw somewhere that 3 or 5 means enabled? What is the difference between vfio and uio, anything in terms of performance?

Comment: VFIO is superior.  You can read about VFIO in the [Linux docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/vfio.html) and [DPDK deep dive](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/memory-in-dpdk-part-2-deep-dive-into-iova.html).